# Как посмотреть количество установленных шрифтов в Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Бонжур трудяги!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как посмотреть в убунту количество установленых шрифтов через терминал?
Заранее спасибо.

Пробовал через `ls -laR | wc` , но уверен, что эта шляпа скорее всего не правильно работает.
Есть подозрение что это делается через утилиту `fc-`

Comment: `fc-list | wc` - можно так, но не уверен, что там не будет повторов.

Comment: @mkkik спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вот команда для получения списка файлов шрифтов, которые использует ваша система.

```
fc-list -f '%{file}\n' | sort
```

Comment: А для их количества получается fc-list -f '%{file}\n' | wc  ?

Comment: да, установка шрифтов это таже процедура копирования файлов, таким образом мы находим все файлы с шрифтами, потом считаем их к-ство